# El recurso requerido no está disponible 404, Tomcat Eclipse JEE

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, tomcat

¿Qué tal?

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy trabajando con un Dynamic Web Project en Java, y como inicio estoy intentando desplegar una tabla desde una base de datos en el JSP. El problema, es que al inicializar el proyecto me salta que el recurso requerido no se encuentra disponible.

Por otra parte, los códigos no me lanzan errores. Intenté hacer debug, sin pero me solicita que corra el proyect.

A continuación dejo los archivos y las pantallas de configuración.

**1) Controlador-Servlet**

```
package facturas.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import facturas.dao.FacturaDao;
import facturas.entity.Factura;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class facturaController
 */
@WebServlet("/FacturaController")
public class FacturaController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FacturaController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        FacturaDao factura = new FacturaDao();
        List<Factura> lFacturas = new ArrayList<Factura>();
        
        lFacturas = factura.leerFactura();
    
        request.setAttribute("listadofacturas", lFacturas);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("factura.jsp").forward(request, response);
        
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**2) Dao**

```
package facturas.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import facturas.db.Conexion;
import facturas.entity.Factura;
import facturas.interfaz.InterfazFacturaDao;

public class FacturaDao implements InterfazFacturaDao{

    @Override
    public boolean crearFactura(Factura factura) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    //lee usuario, convierte cada registro de la consulta en un objeto tipo usuario y lo envía a una lista
    @Override
    public List<Factura> leerFactura(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Connection con = null; //se crea la conexión
        Statement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        String sql = "select * from factura ORDER BY ID";
        
        List<Factura> listaFactura = new ArrayList<Factura>();
        
        try{
            
            con = Conexion.getConnection();
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                Factura f = new Factura();
                f.setIdFactura(rs.getInt(1));
                f.setFecha(rs.getString(2));
                f.setCliente(rs.getString(3));
                f.setTotal(rs.getInt(4));
                listaFactura.add(f);
            }
            stm.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch(SQLException e){
            
            System.out.println("Error al listar los elementos");
        }
        
        
        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean actualizarFactura(Factura factura) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean eliminarFactura(Factura factura) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    
    
    
    
}
```

**3) Interfaz Dao**

```
package facturas.interfaz;


import java.util.List;

import facturas.entity.Factura;


//interfaz para acceder a los distintos métodos de base de datos desde el dao
public interface InterfazFacturaDao {
    
    public boolean crearFactura(Factura factura);
    public List<Factura> leerFactura();
    public boolean actualizarFactura(Factura factura);
    public boolean eliminarFactura(Factura factura);
    

}
```

**4)Entidad**

```
package facturas.entity;

public class Factura {
    
    private int idFactura; 
    private String fecha;
    private String cliente;
    private int total;
    
    public Factura() {
        
    }

    public Factura(int idFactura, String fecha, String cliente, int total) {
        super();
        this.idFactura = idFactura;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getIdFactura() {
        return idFactura;
    }

    public void setIdFactura(int idFactura) {
        this.idFactura = idFactura;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(String cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Factura [idFactura=" + idFactura + ", fecha=" + fecha
                + ", cliente=" + cliente + ", total=" + total + "]";
    }
    
    


}
```

**5) Conexión**

```
package facturas.db;

import java.sql.*;

 
//Conexión implementada como singleton

public class Conexion {

    private static Connection conn = null;
    private String login;
    private String pass;
    private String url;
    private String driver;
    
    
    //recordar cambiar usuario y clave del sistema
    private Conexion(){
        
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        login ="system";
        pass = "paula";
        driver= "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        
        
        try {
            
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pass);

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        if (conn == null){      
            new Conexion();
        }
        return conn;
        
    }
    
    
    /*public void desconexion(){
            
        try{
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            
            System.out.println("Error en desconexión");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args){
        
    Conexion c = new Conexion();
    c.getConnection();
    
    }
    */
    
    
    
    
}
```

**6) Proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**7)Tabla**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

**8) XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>facturas</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FacturaController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FacturaController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>facturas.controller.FacturaController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacturaController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FacturaController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**9) JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Factura</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div align="center">
  <h1>Generación de factura</h1>
  <form action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/register" method="post">
   <table style="with: 80%">
     <tr><td>Ingrese items</td></tr>  
    <tr id ="ingresa-items">
         <td>Asesoría</td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="asesoria" name="asesoria" value="asesoria">
        </td>  
     <td>Cantidad <input type="number" name="cantidad" /></td> 
    </tr>
       <tr id ="ingresa-items">
         <td>Auditoría
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="auditoria" name="auditoria" value="auditoria">
        </td>
     <td>Cantidad <input type="number" name="cantidad" /></td> 
    </tr>
       <tr id ="ingresa-items">
         <td>Capacitación
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="capacitacion" name="capacitacion" value="capacitacion">
        </td>
     <td>Cantidad <input type="number" name="cantidad" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Concepto:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="concepto" /></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
     <td>Rut Profesional:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="profesional" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  
  <table>
  <c:forEach items="${listadofacturas}" var ="factura">
  <tr>
  <td>${factura.getIdFactura()}</td> 
  <td>${factura.getFecha()}</td>
  <td>${factura.getCliente()}</td>
  <td>${factura.getTotal()}</td> 
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quizá si colocas el error o el stackTrace podemos ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Perdon no me habia fijado que estas trabajando con jdbc , veo en las imagenes que te falta la libreria del driver de oracle , como estas trabajando con maven puedes buscarlo en mvnrepository ponerlo en el pom.xml y darle clean an build  , y si fuera el caso de que no esta , descargarlo directamente de la pagina de oracle y añadirlo a las librerias . Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola, Está instalado el Tomcat 6.0

Comment: Hola, la librería está almacenada en lib  y añadida como path a las librerías (ojdbc6.jar)

Comment: Podrias entonces dejar el trace del error que te lanza y quizas pueda ayudarte un poco mas , no he trabajado con base de  datos oracle pero quizas el problema no vaya por ahi .

Answer (score 0):

No se pudo solucinar el error, al parecer es un problema de configuración externo.

Lo que funcionó por el momento para hacer correr el código fue pasar las variables privadas de la clase Factura a públicas, sin modificar el resto del código.

```
package facturas.entity;

public class Factura {
    
    public int idFactura; 
    public String fecha;
    public String cliente;
    public int total;
```